# Why is UISelectMany not returning a collection on a generic property?

Tags: arrays, jsf, jsf-2, collections, selectmanymenu

I have a JSF page that contains a `<h:selectManyMenu>` element. The value attribute points to a generic object defined in a subclass as type `ArrayList<String>`. According to the java documentation the `UISelectMany` should return its value from conversion as a `Collection` of this concrete type. But it is being returned as a `String[]` array. What am I missing?

```
<h:selectManyMenu value="#{parameter.value}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{parameter.valueList}"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

```
public class Parameter<ArrayList<String>> extends ParentClass
{
  private LinkedHashMap<Object, String> valueList;

  public List<SelectItem> getValueList()
  {
    ArrayList<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (Iterator<Object> i = this.valueList.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();)
    {
      Object value = i.next();
      list.add(new SelectItem(value, this.valueList.get(value)));
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T>
{
  private T value;

  public T getValue() { return this.value; }
  public void setValue(T t) { this.value = t; }
}
```

Comment: That getter method is mind-blowingly inefficient. This has a net effect of O(n^3) while it could be O(1) or even zero as the `<f:selectItems>` also supports maps. But it isn't necessarily the cause here. What type exactly is `Object` here? (and why in earth `Object`?) What exactly is return type of `getValue()`?

Comment: Sorry, I shortened this class down because it was very large and I was trying to included only the relevant pieces. You are asking about the valueList which is just a list of Strings pieced together in a parent class. The actual get/set methods in for modifying the value are simple. I will add them to my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to make JSF read the type definition of the property from the subclass. Specifying the `collectionType` attribute did not work and even when trying by creating `@Override` methods in the subclass the backing value being sent to my bean was still a `String[]` array. The only way I was able to get the JSF servlet to return this value as an `ArrayList<String>` was to create an additional pair of get/set property methods in the subclass with `ArrayList<String>` as their return and parameter type.

```
public class Parameter extends ParentClass<ArrayList<String>>
{
  public ArrayList<String> getManyValue() { return super.getValue(); }
  public void setManyValue(ArrayList<String> value) { super.setValue(value); }
}


public abstract class ParentClass<T>
{
  protected T value;
  public T getValue() { return this.value; }
  public void setValue(T value) { this.value = value; }
}


<h:selectManyMenu value="#{parameter.manyValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `getValue()` returns a parameterized type `T` which will after generic type erasure become `Object`. In other words, EL didn't see that it actually returned a `List` but `Object`, and will therefore default to `String[]`.

You need to explicitly specify `collectionType` attribute on the selection component with the FQN of the desired collection implementation as value.

```
<h:selectManyMenu ... collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<f:selectItems>` also supports `Map<K, V>`. Just feed that `LinkedHashMap` to it directly without massaging it into a `List<SelectItem>`. The map key becomes the option value and the map value becomes the option label already. See also [our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

Comment: Adding the collectionType attribute doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'm wondering if the parameterized type of my backing value is defaulting to a String array. In looking at the documentation for UISelectMany, the collectionType attribute is only checked if the value type is not an array:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html

Comment: Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: I'm using glassfish 3.11 (build 12). Looks like my jsf-impl is `Mojarra JSF Implementation 2.1.3 (b02-FCS)`. I wonder if the issue may be that I have multiple instances of the `Parameter` class that are stored in an `Arraylist<ParentClass>` list and then used in my page inside a `ui:dataTable` component.